# Null pointer exception while running Spring project

Tags: java, spring, exception, tomcat

I am unable to figure out reason for NullPointer exception in my Spring project. Sometime project works fine but some time its throwing null pointer Exception here is full stacktrace.

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NullPointerException
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:585)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:455)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:322)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:182)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:184)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:155)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)

root cause

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NullPointerException
org.apache.jsp.redirect_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:72)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:322)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:182)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:184)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:155)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)

root cause

 java.lang.NullPointerException
org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase.generateSessionId(ManagerBase.java:807)
org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase.createSession(ManagerBase.java:653)
org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.doGetSession(Request.java:2892)
org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getSession(Request.java:2315)
org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getSession(RequestFacade.java:898)
org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getSession(RequestFacade.java:910)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:238)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:238)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl._initialize(PageContextImpl.java:146)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.initialize(PageContextImpl.java:125)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.internalGetPageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:112)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.getPageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:65)
org.apache.jsp.redirect_jsp._jspService(redirect_jsp.java:53)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:322)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:182)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:184)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:155)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
```

I am also getting permgenspace error very often. is it related to this?
I changed my project and tomcat VM option (Using NetBean IDE) to:

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

I am using Netbeans IDE 7.3.1 , Apache Tomcat 7.0.37, Spring 3.1.1, Hibernate 3.

Its showing DelegatingFilterProxy in Exception. May be its because of security setting.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<!-- This is where we configure Spring-Security  -->
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" access-denied-page="/auth/denied" >
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/auth/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
    <security:form-login
        login-page="/index"
        authentication-failure-url="/index"
        default-target-url="/welcome"
        />
    <security:logout
        invalidate-session="true"
        logout-success-url="/index" />
</security:http>


<!-- A custom service where Spring will retrieve users and their corresponding access levels  -->
<bean id="loginService" class="com.tcs.ignite.ih.spring.service.LoginService"/>

<!--A service where spring will redirect to proper view after successfull login-->
<!--<bean id="loginSuccessHandler" class="com.tcs.ignite.ih.spring.controller.LoginSuccessHandler" />-->

<!-- Declare an authentication-manager to use a custom userDetailsService -->
<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="loginService">
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>

</beans>
```

**UPDATE :**

When I am trying to access index file,welcome file for application defined in web.xml, with following URL

```
localhost:8080/xxxx/index
```

I recieve following on browser:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Could not get RequestDispatcher for [/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp]: Check that the corresponding file exists within your web application archive!
```

index.jsp in present in my directory.
Do i need to define mapping in spring security intercept url tag for /index?

Comment: It is difficult to answer others without clear information about your problem.Can you explain more about your problem like where you get this error? when deploy war file into jboss? what are all the configuration using like jboss version,eclipse version.

Comment: Do you have a redirect.jsp in your web content??

Comment: Then what is happening is you have a scriptlet in your redirect.jsp which is throwing a Null pointer exception in certain situations. Probably you are accessing a request attribute which is null and performing an operation on it. Try to add a few null checks in the page.

Comment: ok @AdityaKeyal. Thanks i'll check.

Comment: @AdityaKeyal i removed the null RequestAttributes, but still i m facing this problem.

Comment: Can you show the redirect.jsp page source code?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51399/discussion-between-igniter-and-adityakeyal)

Comment: Not sure if this has been answered: let's say you freshly (webapps doesn't have your .war exploded and the .war is not even there; also, "work" folder is clean) start Tomcat. Now you copy the .war to webapps. Until you reach the NPE, do you restart Tomcat? Also, do you make any hot deployments? Or deploy the app and then undeploy and so on?

Comment: Basically, if you leave the application deployed (without restarts, redeploys, hot redeployments) and play with it does it have the problem?

Comment: Also, I don't think you would go wrong if you'd test this with the latest Tomcat 7 version (7.0.53).

Answer (score 2):

The root cause of your problem is a null sessionIdGenerator in tomcat ManagerBase.

A quick look at the [code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-catalina/7.0.25/org/apache/catalina/session/ManagerBase.java/)  : it is possible only is the Manager didn't start yet, or if it is already stopped. My guess here is that your code is using an "already stopped" manager.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I guess that you only have this crash after undeploy/deploy of your app (without restarting tomcat completely).

From where this invalid instance of ManagerBase comes from ?

Well, not easy to say, but I guess that it comes from a ThreadLocal variable not properly cleaned-up when your app is undeployed.
So, you can check your own code to see if your are not misusing a ThreadLocal variable (always clean up all your ThreadLocal variables in a `finally` block in you request filters).

If you don't find anything in your own code:

Inspect carefully all logs (and especially warnings) that occurs when you undeploy/deploy your web-app, they are good chances that you will find something like "resource X cannot be released".

Regarding your recurrent OutOfMemory error : it can be linked to this problem. Indeed, if some ThreadLocal variable aren't clean-up correctly when app is undeployed/deployed it is a memory leak and so at the end it can cause an OutOfMemory.

I hope it helps. (Posting logs when app is undeployed/deployed may be interesting.)

Answer (score 1):

The exception actually comes when the redirect page requires session and the page context setup machanism (PageContextImpl.java:146) tries to create a session. However the session id generator is somehow null this time

```
    ManagerBase.java:807.....

     protected String generateSessionId() {

            String result = null;

            do {
                if (result != null) {                   
                    duplicates++;
                }

                result = sessionIdGenerator.generateSessionId();
//There is issue in the above line - sessionIdGenerator is null this time

            } while (sessions.containsKey(result));

            return result;
        }
```

Issue like this which occurs intermittently have been reported [here](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54315) and there is lots of comment on the issue.
See if there is some hint which can help you out.

Comment: can you please take look at spring security configuration, i think this exception is because of spring security.

Comment: Your configuration seems to be fine. How is redirect.jsp being called ? I have used Spring security with Tomcat 7 for a long time and can't recall having such issue ?

Comment: Its not redirect.jsp it is index.jsp. Its welcome file for project(web.xml). I have updated the stacktrace.

Comment: When i tried to access index page with null pointer exception i recieved 500 error for index.jsp even though index jsp is present in directory. Please check the updated question for detail. Thanks!

Comment: Is it present at /WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp ?

Comment: yeah. its present thats why i am able to login. 500 error comes when i try to access page at time of null pointer exception.

Answer (score -1):

Have you configured the view resolver in application context for the jsp? like below

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="prefix" value="/pages/" />
            <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
            <property name="exposeContextBeansAsAttributes" value="true"/> 
</bean>
```

if it is configured then check whether the controller has the correct definition.
if above are performed correctly, then it should be with the spring security configuration.